# Prior Art Request - US Pat. No. 8,380,541 Theranos / Walgreen / Stanford U

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, theranos, us8380541

This is an issued patent.  It is related to a Theranos / Stanford / Walgreen project currently on going.

U.S. Patent No. 8,380,541
Priority date 9/26/2011
Issued February 13, 2013

A sample claim is:

> 1. A method of evaluating a biological sample collected from a subject, said method comprising:
>
>    (a) receiving data transmitted from a Clinical Laboratory Improvement Amendments (CLIA)-compliant device placed in or on the subject or at a site selected from the group consisting of a retailer site, the subject's home, or a health assessment/treatment location,
>      wherein the device is configured to process the biological sample by:
>
>    (i) receiving the biological sample;
>
>    (ii) preparing the biological sample and yielding raw data for a subsequent qualitative and/or quantitative evaluation of said biological sample; and
>
>    (iii) transmitting electronically the raw data to an authorized analytical facility and/or an affiliate thereof for performance of said subsequent evaluation;
>
>    (b) analyzing the raw data transmitted from the device at the authorized analytical facility and/or the affiliate thereof, to provide said evaluation of said biological sample, wherein said analysis is performed using a processor alone or in conjunction with an individual affiliated with the authorized analytical facility; and
>
>    (c) providing oversight of integrity of said analysis and operation of said CLIA-compliant device such that results generated from said analysis can be utilized by a health care professional for diagnosis or treatment of said subject, wherein the oversight is performed using a processor alone or in conjunction with an individual affiliated with the authorized analytical facility, and wherein the authorized analytical facility is a CLIA-compliant laboratory.

Can you find anything closer than:

Lee et al., A simle and Smart Telemedicine Device for Developing Regions: a pocket size colorimetric reader, Lab on a Chip, issue 1, 2011. (First published 11/26/2010)

“We have proposed a novel mobile healthcare platform, combining a pocket-sized colorimetric reader (13.5 × 6.5 × 2.5 cm3) and commercially available 10-parameter urinalysis paper strips (glucose, protein, glucose, bilirubin, urobilinogen, ketones, nitrite, pH, specific gravity, erythrocytes, and leukocytes), capable of sending data with a smart phone. The reader includes a novel colorimetric multi-detection module, which consists of three-chromatic light-emitting diodes, silicon photodiodes and a novel poly(methylmethacrylate) (PMMA) optical splitter. We employed data reading methods using conversions of the signal data (red, blue, and green) to the hue (H) color map or the Y model data, and used a curve-fitting method for the quantification. The reader is battery-powered, inexpensive, light-weight, and very speedy in analysis. And, it was applied to detection of a thousand of human urine samples and demonstrated reliable quantification of urinary glucose and protein. The features can be used by unskilled people on-site to transfer the analyzed data to experts off-site.”

Comment: I edited the post to include the actual wording of claim 1. When you include claim language and say "Yes, that is the claim", it would be better if it actually was the complete claim.

Comment: LMFAO..I was being nice.  The attorney who added " selected from the group consisting of a retailer site, the subject's home, or a health assessment/treatment location" should be fired.  Add a school/university/assisted living facility and you don't have infringement.  And what is "the subject's home"?  If they sleep with a coworker in that person's house, is that the "subject's home"? Or their parent's house they bought?  Is that the "subject's home"? I can't believe an attorney charged for that application.

Comment: I agree that the wording you point out is odd, especially in an independent claim. If the person simply being at a different location from the analysis location wasn't enough then naming the places would be a very thin basis for patentability.